# Understanding the print format %.3 in python

Tags: python

Can someone help me with the explanation of what the "'f %" meaning in the following code?

```
print('Slope: %.3f' % lr.w_[1])
```

Comment: Just a comment: This is old string notation. Have a look at `str.format()` instead.

Comment: @Anton vBR building off of that, here is OPs code converted to use `.format` : `print('Slope: {.3f}'.format(lr.w_[1])`

Comment: If I may, it should be `print('Slope: {:.3f}.format(lr.w_[1])`. There was a `:` missing in @Woohoojin's comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) is a list of string formatting options in Python. You use a `%` as a placeholder, which is replaced by `lr.w_[1]` in this case. The `f` then refers to "Floating point decimal format". The `.3` indicates to round to 3 places after the decimal point.

Answer (score 5):

```
%.3f
```

`f`: Floating point, which means that the value that is going to be printed is a real number.

`.3` is for the number of decimals after the point. That means that the real value to be printed will have 3 digits after the point.

---

For example:

```
print('%.3f' % 3.14159)          # Prints 3.142
print('%.2f' % 3.141592653589)   # Prints 3.14
```

Comment: "f" stands for floating point. The integer (here 3) represents the number of decimals after the point. "%.3f" will print a real number with 3 figures after the point.

Comment: @Kefeng91 I missed that this was in question too. Thank you very much, answer updated!

Answer (score 5):

It prints a decimal number, with 3 decimal digit accuracy.

```
In [1]: print('Slope: %.3f' % 1.123)
Slope: 1.123

In [2]: print('Slope: %.3f' % 1.12345)
Slope: 1.123

In [3]: print('Slope: %.3f' % 1.1)
Slope: 1.100

In [4]: print('Slope: %.3f' % 1.1237)
Slope: 1.124
```

As you can see by the 4th example is rounds by standard rounding rules